# How to add .htaccess file to my Visual Studio solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .htaccess, visual-studio-2012

My need is to Add `Expires` headers - while Googling I got the solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972629/add-expires-headers). But where this file is located? Is it possible add it to my Visual Studio solution? Is it necessary to refer such file in master page?

Comment: Are you sure your site is deployed on Apache server? It is not very common to folks using Apache (i.e. on LAMP stack) to use Visual Studio...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need .htaccess? To my knowledge there is no point of using it with IIS  (you can search for http://www.bing.com/search?q=iis+htaccess )... If you'd be looking for just expire headers your post is simple duplicate of one of many posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825497/iis-7-5-how-do-you-add-a-dynamic-http-expires-header

Comment: To clarify: IIS does not support `.htaccess` as-is - you need to use `web.config` instead, but I'm not sure if that supports `Expires` headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set an Expires header for static content in IIS with ASP.NET you need to do it in the web.config.  I blogged about this a while back [here](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2012/01/19/improve-performance-with-static-file-caching.aspx).

But here is the code to add a default 7 day expiration to the `<system.webServer>` node of your web.config.

```
<staticContent>
 <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
</staticContent>
```